# Solr DataImportHandler cache with multiple keys

Tags: caching, indexing, solr, dataimporthandler

I'm trying to index data from a database using the Solr DataImportHandler. The database contains products defined by a class and with multiple features with the following relevant tables:

- `product` table contains a PK `product_id` and a FK `class_id`
- `product_feature` table contains a PK (`product_id` & `feature_id`)
- `class_feature` table contains a PK (`class_id` & `feature_id`)

For each `product` I need to index multiple `product_feature` and for each of those I need to index multiple `class_feature`. I also need to cache sub-entities for improved performance. The entity-definitions in the config look like this:

```
<entity name="product" query="select product_id, class_id, ... from product">
  ...
  <entity name="product_feature" query="select product_id, feature_id, ... from product_feature"
      cacheImpl="SortedMapBackedCache" cacheKey="product_id" cacheLookup="product.product_id">
    ...
    <entity name="class_feature" query="select class_id, feature_id, ... from class"
        cacheImpl="SortedMapBackedCache" where="class_id=product.class_id AND feature_id=product_feature.feature_id">
      ...
    </entity>
  </entity>
</entity>
```

Notice in the innermost entity `class_feature`, I'm defining a `where` attribute matching two FKs, one on the outermost `product` and another on the direct parent `product_feature`. This doesn't seem to work. How must I define an entity cache to match on multiple keys?